# Proof involving a simple inequality

Tags: inequality

I'm struggling to prove the following inequality (for $0 \leq a \leq c$ and $0 \leq b \leq c$)
$$|a-b| \leq c.$$
I see that it is true by drawing a number line and putting the numbers $a, b$ and $c$ there, but I have no idea how to prove it formally. It seems so trivial that it's tempting to write "obviously the following holds next to it." I tried playing around with triangle inequality but I got only this:
$$|a-b| \leq |a-c| + |b-c|=2c-a-b,$$
which is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-c \leq -b \leq a-b \leq a \leq c$$
hence $|a-b|\leq c$.

Answer (score 2):

$-c=0-c\leq a-b\leq c-0=c$, when you use inequalities that are given for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a different approach, note that

$$|a-b|=\max(a,b)-\min(a,b)\le\max(a,b,c)-\min(0,a,b)$$

holds for *any* three real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$. (That is, adding extra options can only make max's bigger and min's smaller.) The assumptions $0\le a,b\le c$, so that $\max(a,b,c)=c$ and $\min(0,a,b)=0$, now do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

What is $\color {red}{\text{max} |a-b| }$?

$$\begin{align}\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black}{\text{max} |a-b| =|c-0|=|0-c|=c≤c.}}}\end{align}$$